# OCM or Nodes in JCR?

Tags: content-management-system, pojo, jackrabbit, jcr

We are developing a CMS based on JCR/Sling/JSP/Felix/etc.

What I found so far is using Nodes are very straight forward and flexible. But my concern is over time it could become too hard to maintain and manage.

So, is it wise to invest in using a OCM? Would it be just an extra layer of complexity? What's the real benefit in OCM if there's any? Or it's better for us to stick to Nodes instead?

And lastly, is Jackrabbit OCM the best option for us if we are to go down that path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience I can say it severly depends on your situation if OCM is a useful tool for your project or not.

The real problem in using OCM (in my personal experience) is when the definition of a class used in existing persisted data (as objects) in the repository has changed. For example: you found it necessary to change some members and methods of a class to match with functionality changes. By this I mean that the class definition of the persisted data object in the repository no longer matches the definition of actual class. When a persisted data is saved to the jcr repository it is usually saved in a format that java understands in terms of serialization. Which means that when something changes to the definition of the used class, the saved data in the repository can no longer be correctly interpreted by java. This issue tends to lead to complex deployment where you need to convert old persisted data objects to the new definition and save them again in the repository to make sure you can still use "old" but still required persisted data.

What does work (in my opinion) is using a framework that allows to map nodes and node properties to java objects directly (for example by using annotations) and the other way around (persist a java object to the repository as a JCR node where the java member fields are actual node properties). This way you stick to the data representation of jcr (nodes with properties) and can still map them to the members of a java class.

I've used a framework like this in a cms called AEM (of Adobe) before, although I must mention this is in a OSGI context (but the prinicipe still stands). The used framework basically allowed maximum flexibility and persists the java object as a JCR node and the other way around. Because it mapped directly to the jcr definition, code changes in the class and members ment just changing annotations, and old persisted data was still usuable without much effort.

Comment: We are expecting our data structure to evolve over time. Which is one of the main reasons we picked JCR for storage. Sounds like OCM would provide convenience initially, but could hinder flexibility down the line. I think you are spot on.
I will take a look at AEM. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that the framework I'm talking about is seperate from AEM, it's called slice (from cognify), but plugs in great in AEM (or any other OSGI environment using jcr as a backend)

Comment: That makes sense now. :) I haven't had time to dig deep into it. But it looks like just what we need. Thank you very much!

Comment: One of the powerful benefits of a JCR repository is that the schema/structure can change at any time, allowing your applications to evolve over time as needs/requirements change. Using an OCM layer will restrict this flexibility. This is fine in some applications, but very undesired in others.